# how to check if a value exists in a mysql table using c# and open another form in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a mySql table **initialentry** composed of 1 column **aircraft_name**.
What I am intending to do is enter a value in a 
`Combobox` to check if it exists in the table.
If it does I need a new form to open instead of the current one.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //int isP = 0;
    string a = comboBox1.Text;
    string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";

    string sql = "SELECT count (*) FROM [initialentry] WHERE aircraft_number = @a";
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aircraft_number", a);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                label1.Text = "Record exists";

            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Record does not exist";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> I get the following error : Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: Your query always has records. One record exactly - the count which is `0` or greater. Check the content, not if there is a result.

Comment: You're using different parameter names at least

Comment: your parameter is @a , not @aircraft_number

Answer (score 2):

In your query string, you declare the @a parameter but in your AddWithValue method, you try to ad another parameter.

```
 string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM initialentry WHERE aircraft_number = @a";

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aircraft_number", a);
```

You need to change the code like this :

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", aircraftnumber); //aircraftnumber = your air craft number which you want to give as parameter.
```

Remark:
As your query will return only one value, you don't need to use a SqlReader object.

You can use ExecuteScalar of your SqlCommandObject:

```
    void CheckAirCraft()
    {
        string a = comboBox1.Text;
        string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";

        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM initialentry WHERE aircraft_number = @a";
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
                var result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Record exists";

                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Record does not exist";
                }
            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: I got the following error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM [initialentry] WHERE aircraft_number = 'l1201'' at line 1

Comment: Can you try this query in your MySQL editor ? : SELECT count (*) FROM [initialentry] WHERE aircraft_number = 1

Comment: Can you try like this in your code? : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM initialentry WHERE aircraft_number = @a

Comment: Apparently, MySQL doesn't like [ ] symbols.

Comment: I already tried it and the same error appeared. the Program.cs opened, highliting the **Application.run(new Form1());** and the error box titled :
**MySQLException was unhandled**

Comment: May be the table name or the column name is not correct ? Can you post your final buttonclick method please ?

Comment: i got it. I should have written the data title first : aircraft.initialentry. now it works well. thank you

Comment: Will this only work with integers, or will it also work with strings? It doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: It works with all other types. Can you give some details ? It can be another thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = comboBox1.Text;
        string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";

        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM initialentry WHERE aircraft_number = @a";
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
                var result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Record exists";

                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Record does not exist";
                }
```